# Is there a slope symbol in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, symbols

I plotted a tangent line to a curve, and I want to indicate the slope of the tangent on the plot using that little right angle symbol. Can MATLAB do this? Do I have to plot my own little triangle to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addign to Jagte's answer, this is how to add text to a plot in a way that will add those special Tex characters:

```
text(x_pos,y_pos,'\angle \theta(z)')
```

where `x_pos`, `y_pos` are the relevant numbers where you want to write that text .

Answer (score 2):

In matlab you can use some tex symbols. Follow the following link

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html#String

on that page look for the "TeX Character Sequence Table"